# Difference in Java And Python when functions return values

Tags: java, python-3.5

Code In Java:-

```
int check_prime()//Function to check if a number is a prime number
{
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());//Number to be checked
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Code in Python:-

```
def check_prime():#Function to check if a number is a prime number
n1=input("Enter the number")#Number to be checked
n=int(n1)
for i in range(2,n,1):
    if n%i==0:
        return False
return True
```

In Java whenever a Function returns a value,it terminates itself and does not execute any further statements. Thus if a number is not prime it returns 0 and stops.
Will the same thing happen in python too? Because as far as I could test it didn't happen.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Instead of rigorously testing it, look at the code. Is it functionally the same? If it is, it will do the same thing.

Comment: You can't use `return` as a method name in Java. It is a reserved word.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry about that Logan.

Comment: @Ritesh_BM No problem. I was just notifying you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loops are doing very different things. I believe your python loop should be:

```
for i in range(2, n):
```

Since you left out the range generator, your loop looped through the tuple (2, n, 1), instead of the sequence of numbers beginning at 2 and stopping before n. You also don't need to specify the step argument. It's 1 by default.

The return statement works the same way in both languages: It terminates the function.

Also there is a boolean type in Java you should be using instead of int to represent true/false values.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry about that.